# Como usar corretamente memcpy?

Tags: c, array, funções

Estou tentando criar um programa em que terá dois vetores :

```
char vetor_origem[20] = "algoritmo";
char vetor_copia[20]
```

No que se pode ver, no `vetor_origem` eu tenho a palavra algoritmo escrita, e eu quero copiar a string dele para o `vetor_copia`, eu sei que usando `memcpy()` é possível fazer isto, mas eu quero muito mais do que isto.

Eu tenho uma função chamada `substring()` em que nela, o usuário irá colocar a `posição inicial` e a `quantidade` de letras a serem copiadas do `vetor_origem` para o `vetor_copia`, mas pela documentação do `memcpy()` fala que somente pode ter 3 argumentos, sendo que eu preciso de 4 argumentos. Ficaria assim, do jeito que eu quero :

```
    char vetor_origem[20] = "algoritmo";
    char vetor_copia[20]
    substring(0,4) --> "algo"
```

Ele iria copiar a partir da posição inicial e a quantidade de letras, usando o `memcpy()` chamado pela função `substring()`.

Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Exemplo testado: https://pastebin.com/vp48Hizz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) assim

```
char vetor_copia[20] = { 0 }; // Inicializa o vetor com terminador null
memcpy(vetor_copia, &vetor_origem[posicao_inicial], quantidade); // Copia os caracteres
```

- `posicao_inicial` funciona como um *offset*. Assim, será passada à função a string iniciando com a posição inicial desejada
- `quantidade` indicará a quantia de *bytes* que deseja copiar. Como cada *char* ocupa 1 *byte*, passar esse valor para a função já resolve.

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/IsDI/0).

Comment: Muito obrigado mercador, funcionou do jeito que eu estava querendo, só não estava sabendo como colocar desta forma.